# How can I profile booting of a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, profiling

Simple problem, I have a legacy Rails 2.3 application and it takes quite long to do anything. `rake` takes over 25 seconds, but it doesn't look like anything is really happening.

Is there any simple way I can just get some kind of profiler dump from the time when the app is loading, to see which methods take the longest time?

A solution for both Rails 2.3 and 3.1 would be even more helpful.

Comment: @rkb Currently REE, but I can use any other version for profiling, as all of the gems are 1.9 compatible.

Answer (score 10):

Profile a rake task that requires the rails environment, something like this:

```
 desc "Load it"
 task :loadit => :environment do

 end
```

then profile with ruby-prof

```
ruby -Ilib -S ruby-prof -p graph_html `which rake` loadit > profile.html
```

It *ought* to work with rails 2.3 have only tested it on 3.x but I see no reason why it should not work.

Comment: `rake environment` is a task that does just that--loads the Rails environment.

Comment: Ah yeah, you could as well run just rake environment I guess, but maybe you'd like to try out some methods in the rake task like FooModel.all or something.

Answer (score 1):

You could start your application with a profiler hooked in, e.g. [ruby-prof](https://github.com/rdp/ruby-prof) or [perftools.rb](https://github.com/tmm1/perftools.rb). While it's still starting up, launch a HTTP query against it, which would try go `GET` a `/kill_me` route as soon as the application starts. `/kill_me` could cause your application to gracefully die by calling `exit`. As a result you've got a profile of your startup.